# Can we overload an overridden method?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, overloading

I am new to C#. I understand the concept of inheritance. I am trying to know whether overridden methods can be overloaded, I googled it but can't find a good answer. Also I tried with following code. In code, I am accessing the method that is overloaded method of overridden method, when I debug this program it does not return any output on the screen. So I am confused about whether overridden method can be overloaded or not?

```
public class method1
{
    public virtual void PrintName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
    }
}

public class method2 : method1
{
    public override void PrintName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World Overriden");
    }

    public string PrintName(String strPolymorphism)
    {
        return strPolymorphism;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        method2 m2 = new method2();
        m2.PrintName("method overloading is possible?");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `m2.PrintName` just returns the string it receives. It doesn't do anything with it. If you do so, you will see output.

```
public string PrintName(String strPolymorphism)
{
    this.PrintName(); // first write the output of `PrintName` to the console

    Console.WriteLine("Called PrintName with: " + strPolymorphism);
    return strPolymorphism;
}
```

Your **overload** `m2.PrintName` has nothing to do with your **overridden** `PrintName` method with a different signature in the `method2` or `method1` class. Signature matters. A lot!

Answer (score 5):

What you are doing is [*overloading*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229029%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) not *overriding*. You can add a method with same name and different signature as many times as you want.

In your method you are just returning the `string` and not displaying it. That method has nothing to do with other overload that takes `0` parameter.

Comment: but why,In my program overloading method doesn't return output?

Comment: it returns the string. You are ignoring it. `Console.WriteLine(m2.PrintName("method overloading is possible?"));`

Comment: @SVT002 use below code :class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        method2 m2 = new method2();
        string val =m2.PrintName("method overloading is possible?");
  Console.WriteLine(val); 
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

From the C# standard

> Overloading of methods permits a class, struct, or interface to declare multiple methods with the same name, provided their signatures are unique within that class, struct, or interface.

You can overload the method as long as its signature is unique within the class, the base class is not considered. The reason nothing is printed is because in the overloaded method you are just returning the passed in value rather than printing it.

```
public string PrintName(String strPolymorphism)
{
    return strPolymorphism; // Do you mean Console.WriteLine(strPolymorphism);
}
```